# Remove trailing spaces from hyperlinks

Tags: php, regex

I want to prevent spaces in hyperlinks on a UGC site. I have written regular expression it works perfect except its not removing trailing space from link and anchor text.

Here is my code:

```
$text = '< a href =   "   http://www.examplesite.com/       "> Example site   </a>';

$text = preg_replace('#(<(\s+)*a(\s+)*href(\s+)*=(\s+)*("|\')(\s+)*([^"]+)("|\')>(\s+)*([^<]+)(\s+)*</a>)#','<a href="$8">$11</a> ',$text);
```

### Output

```
<a href="http://www.examplesite.com/      ">Example site  </a>
```

URLs  also  contain spaces i.e. http://www.examplesite.com/blog/a page with space.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("{<\s*a\s*href\s*=\s*(\"|')\s*([^\s]+)\s*\\1>\s*(.*?)\s+</a>}","<a href='$2'>$3</a>",$text);
```

Comment: That should do it but with $3 and $4 (not $2 and $3).

Comment: It won't work with urls having spaces, http://www.examplesite.com/blog/a page with space.html i have updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in regex but it seems you need a way to backtrack, you read all the way up to the closing `"` but you have to backtrack to the last non space character. I got no clue how to do that so what I would do is after you got your semi-cleared string

a) either str_replace or b) write a second regex

```
$str = str_replace(" '>","'>", $count);
$str = str_replace(" \">","\">", $count); 
$str = str_replace(" </a>","</a>", $count);
```

recursively until no more replacements can be done should work. Its primitive I know, but should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to remove extra spaces

```
function  RemoveExtraSpaces($str)
{
    while(strpos($str,"  "))
    {
        $str = str_replace("  ", "", $str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: this will remove everything mate. You will end up with something like <ahref="http://www.example.com/a/bcd">examplesite</a> which is not valid.

Comment: change str_raplaces("  ", "", $str); to str_raplaces("  ", " ", $str);

Comment: Its been some time I used php, but what good would replacing a space with a space do? If this somehow does solve the problem please edit your answer with an explanation.